# How can I number the lines of a .txt file and edit certain information from a selected line? (Python)

Tags: python, txt

I have a .txt file with the names and information as below

John, 87, 64, 72, 79, 81, Yes

Steve, 32, 45, 29, 37, 34, No

I am trying to read from the .txt file and number each name so that the specific name can be selected by entering the number and information from the selected name can be edited.

I want to be able to choose from two options "to edit one of the amounts" or "change from No to Yes"

```
line_count = 0

with open("results.txt", 'r') as r_file:
            for line in r_file:
                results_info = line.split(",")
                line_count += 1
                print("\n" + str(line_count) + " " + " Name:\t" + results_info[0]
                        + "\n   " + "Subject_1:\t " + results_info[1]
                        + "\n   " + "Subject_2:\t" + results_info[2]
                        + "\n   " + "Subject_3:\t" + results_info[3]
                        + "\n   " + "Subject_4:\t" + results_info[4]
                        + "\n   " + "Subject_5:\t" + results_info[5]
                        + "\n   " + "Pass?\t" + results_info[6])
                  
student_select = input("\nEnter the number of the student to edit: ")
```

I've gotten this far but I am stuck when it comes to the rest.

edit:

1. Never added subject 5 to the code
2. I would like to write the changes made back to the .txt file
3. Sorry, I don't think that I was clear enough. I'd like to display the list of all the students numbered. From there give the option to select a student by entering their number and then the option to edit a grade or change pass to yes.

Comment: You are numbering them from `0-len(N)`. A list does this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have 3 tasks here: read data, manage user input, save data if something has been modified.

And the best structure to handle this is a `dict` of `list`s (I kept to your idea of numbering the rows, but you could easily have the student's name as key instead). The code could be something like this (some more checks are needed on user input, of course):

```
def edit_info(fname):
    #read data
    with open(fname, 'r') as r_file:
        info = {}
        for i,line in enumerate(r_file):
            info[str(i)] = line.rstrip().split(', ')
    #prompt user and update data
    dirty = False
    while True:
        for k,vl in info.items():
        print(f'{k:2} {vl[0]:10} {" ".join(vl[1:-1])} {vl[-1]:3}')
        student = input('Enter Student number or X to exit... ')
        if student == 'X':
            break
            if student in info:
                while True:
                    subject = input('Enter Subject number, P to set pass to yes, or X to stop editing... ')
                    if subject == 'X':
                        break
                    if subject == 'P':
                        info[student][-1] = 'Yes'
                        dirty = True
                    elif '1' <= subject <= str(len(info[student])-1):
                        subject = int(subject)
                        newvalue = input(
                            f'Enter new value for Student {student} for Subject {subject} (currently {info[student][subject]})... ')
                        info[student][subject] = newvalue
                        dirty = True
    #save data if needed
    if dirty:
        with open(fname, 'w') as w_file:
            for vl in info.values():
                w_file.write(', '.join(vl)+'\n')
    print('Completed')
```

Comment: I'd like to display all the students and then give the option to select a specific student by looking at the list.

Comment: I also want to display in the format of the name and the each subject and pass on a new line as in my code.

Comment: Did you run the code? It lists the students and their data in a tabular form and allows you to select a student, and then what to edit. You may want to add a header line with the subjects names - just `print` an `f-string` immediately after the first `while` statement

Comment: Yes, it just gives me the first line of student and details then if i enter X it gives the 2nd line. The indexing is out at the first for statement.

Comment: I shifted everything over after the second for statement which made it not work. I've since shifted only the print statement and now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: The only thing is that it doesn't print the statement to the format that I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Python too so I will do it in a stupid way sorry. Here is my code which changes all the info of the nth student as all the input you made

```
def select_student_to_edit(input_num):
    all_result=[]
    result0 = input('Edit name element: ')
    result1 = " " + input('Edit 1th element: ')
    result2 = " " + input('Edit 2th element: ')
    result3 = " " + input('Edit 3th element: ')
    result4 = " " + input('Edit 4th element: ')
    result5 = " " + input('Edit 5th element: ')
    result6 = " " + input('Edit Yes/No element: ') + "\n"
    with open('test1', 'r+') as f:
        
        if input_num>1: 
            for i in range(1,input_num):
                 all_result.append(f.readline()) #If input_num = n then read n-1 line before, add all of the to a all_result list contain all lines
       
        #Start modifying the line(student) that you want to:
        
        results_info = f.readline().split(",") #Split all info into list to modify
        results_info[0] = result0
        results_info[1] = result1
        results_info[2] = result2
        results_info[3] = result3
        results_info[4] = result4
        results_info[5] = result5
        results_info[6] = result6
        
        all_result.append(",".join(results_info)) #add modified studen to all_result list

        #Add all rest lines into all_result list
        rest_line = f.readlines()
        for line in rest_line:
            all_result.append(line)
        print(all_result)
    
    #Write all line(student) in all_result into the old file
    with open('test1','w+') as f:
        for line in all_result:
            f.write(line)


select_student_to_edit(int(input('Enter the student you want to change info (nth): ')))
```

Comment: If you want to edit Yes or No then you can just add something like result_info[5] = 'No' or "Yes' inside the for line in f part.  Of course if  you want to write on the file then it will be quite hard

Comment: Yes, I would like to write whatever changes are made to the file. I also forgot to add subject 5 to my code so I added the line for that. Thanks

Comment: @Morifak I edit my code so that you can change it from no to yes yes to no. My idea is quite simple. Just create an all_result list containing all the info about every student from the file. Each element of the list is the info about one student. You modified the student(element) you want. Then you write all the all_result list back to the old file.